# Statistics: how to equate two estimators

Tags: statistics

$$ E( \sum\limits_{i=1}^k a_i X_i )= \sum\limits_{i=1}^k a_i E(X_i ) $$

How can i make this work? I'm just really lost for the intermediate stages.

Comment: Hint: Use linearity.

Answer (score 0):

There are theorems about the E() (means) operator. It is a linear operator. So you should be able to prove from it's definition that:
$$E(aX)=aE(X)$$
and
$$E(X+Y)=E(X)+E(Y)$$

Proceed by induction.